# Declare a string var with multiple lines in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i declare a variable in jquery with multiple lines like,

original variable:

```
var h = '<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label><input type="button" value="Visit Hotel"><input type="button" value="Exit">';
```

the variable i want to declare:

```
var h = '<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label>
              <input type="button" value="Visit Hotel">
              <input type="button" value="Exit">';
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `\` to indicate that the line has not finished yet.

```
var h= '<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label> \
              <input type="button" value="Visit Hotel"> \
              <input type="button" value="Exit">';
```

**Note:** When you use `\`, the whitespace in the following line will also be a part of the string, like this

```
console.log(h);
```

**Output**

```
<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label>               <input type="button" value="Visit Hotel">               <input type="button" value="Exit">
```

The best method is to use the one suggested by Mr.Alien in the comments section, concatenate the strings, like this

```
var h = '<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label>' +
              '<input type="button" value="Visit Hotel">' +
              '<input type="button" value="Exit">';

console.log(h);
```

**Output**

```
<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label><input type="button" value="Visit Hotel"><input type="button" value="Exit">
```

Comment: +1 or you can just add `\n` if you want to put a enter in output like `<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label>\n              <input type="button" value="Visit Hotel">\n              <input type="button" value="Exit">';`

Comment: @imsiso This looks like HTML. Why would he want to append `\n`? :)

Comment: @thefourtheye - maybe because of improving HTML formatting and/or hide PHP extension and showing page as its a HTML? I just guessed that (-:.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks yaar :) It was a very good suggestion, so I took it in.

Comment: That easy? LOL... thanks for the answer...
I was doing some html append to a table which is 
"<tr>..alot of element..</tr>" and doing it in one line is really killing me..  I tried searching in the nets and just cant find it. Thanks a lot!!

Here is my actual code..
var lowertr='<tr id="trLowerEdit_ID_'+staffid+'" class="trLower_cls">\          <td><label>Username</label></td>\        <td><input type="text" value="'+username+'"></td>\
</tr>';

Answer (score 10):

### Edit

Now you could also make a use of ES6 Template Literals.

```
let str = `
  some
  random
  string
`;
```

You can also interpolate the variables in the above string with an ease, without using concatenation, like:

```
let somestr = 'hello',
str = `
  ${somestr}
  world
`;
```

---

#### Old answer

[@thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21202786/1542290) answer is perfect, but if you want, you can also use concatenation here because sometimes `\` will be misleading, as you will think those are literal characters ..

```
var h = '<label>Hello World, Welcome to the hotel</label>';
    h += '<input type="button" value="Visit Hotel"> '; 
    h += '<input type="button" value="Exit">';

console.log(h);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjAPV/)

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 you can achieve this by simply declaring a variable as:

```
const sampleString  = `Sample
                       text
                       here`;
```

This in return evaluates to `'Sample \ntext\nhere'`
You can read all about ES6 rules of multiline strings from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en#multiline-strings).