# Quotes script not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script to display random quotes after clicking on button. Please help me understand why it is not working.

```js
function quotes() {
    var aquote = new Array;
    aquote[0] = "\"Nobody exists on purpose. Nobody belongs anywhere. We're all 
    going to die.Come watch TV.\"";
    aquote[1] = "\"Listen, Morty, I hate to break it to you but what people call 
    love is just a chemical reaction that compels animals to breed.It hits
    hard, Morty, then it slowly fades, leaving you stranded in a failing
    marriage.I did it.Your parents are gonna do it.Break the cycle, Morty.
    Rise above.Focus on science."\"";
    aquote[2] = "\"Weddings are basically funerals with cake.\""
    aquote[3] = "\"There is no God, Summer. Gotta rip that band-aid off now 
    you’ ll thank me later.\""
    aquote[4] = "\"I’m sorry, but your opinion means very little to me.\""
    aquote[5] = "\"Being nice is something stupid people do to hedge their 
    bets.\""
    
    rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * aquote.length);
    document.getElementById("quote").value = aquote[rdmQuote];
}
window.onload = quotes;
```

```html
<marquee><p id="quote"></p></marquee>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare a string var with multiple lines in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202782/declare-a-string-var-with-multiple-lines-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Difference between ".innerHTML" and ".value" in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31225901/8173752)

Comment: Text literals in JavaScript can not just go from one line on to the next - check the duplicate in that regard. And in general, familiarize yourself with your browser's developer tools and specifically the console - that would have already told you that you have an error in that part, so that you could have tried to research this a little more purposefully.

Comment: Aargh, a `<marquee>`. And look at your browser console, you will see: *SyntaxError: unterminated string literal*.

Comment: I already fixed that issue

Comment: `new Array` should probably be `new Array()` if you're going the constructor route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error on the `aquote[1]` line. In the end it should be `Focus on science.\"";` instead of `Focus on science."\"";`. Note the third quote from the end.

Once that is fixed, you need to set the `innerText` of `quote`, rather than its value. See the working snippet below:

```html
<script>
function quotes(){
 var aquote = new Array;
  aquote[0]="\"Nobody exists on purpose. Nobody belongs anywhere. We're all going to die. Come watch TV.\"";
  aquote[1]="\"Listen, Morty, I hate to break it to you but what people call love is just a chemical reaction that compels animals to breed. It hits hard, Morty, then it slowly fades, leaving you stranded in a failing marriage. I did it. Your parents are gonna do it. Break the cycle, Morty. Rise above. Focus on science.\"";
  aquote[2]="\"Weddings are basically funerals with cake.\""
  aquote[3]="\"There is no God, Summer. Gotta rip that band-aid off now you’ll thank me later.\""
  aquote[4]="\"I’m sorry, but your opinion means very little to me.\""
  aquote[5]="\"Being nice is something stupid people do to hedge their bets.\"";
rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*aquote.length);
document.getElementById("quote").innerText=aquote[rdmQuote];
}
window.onload=quotes;
</script>


<marquee><p id="quote"></p></marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems. First line breaks are messing up where you declare the values. Second, you have an extra " mark on one of the lines. And last, you need to change the innerHTML not the value. Try this instead:

```
function quotes() {
 var aquote = new Array;
  aquote[0]="\"Nobody exists on purpose. Nobody belongs anywhere. We're all going to die. Come watch TV.\"";
  aquote[1]="\"Listen, Morty, I hate to break it to you but what people call love is just a chemical reaction that compels animals to breed. It hits hard, Morty, then it slowly fades, leaving you stranded in a failing marriage. I did it. Your parents are gonna do it. Break the cycle, Morty. Rise above. Focus on science.\"";
  aquote[2]="\"Weddings are basically funerals with cake.\"";
  aquote[3]="\"There is no God, Summer. Gotta rip that band-aid off now you’ll thank me later.\"";
  aquote[4]="\"I’m sorry, but your opinion means very little to me.\"";
  aquote[5]="\"Being nice is something stupid people do to hedge their bets.\"";
rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*aquote.length);
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=aquote[rdmQuote];
}

window.onload=quotes;
```

Comment: Please note that it's recommended that "marquee" should be avoided:

"This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)